# Default values in input fields versus text areas in thymeleaf (spring boot)

Tags: spring-boot, thymeleaf, textarea

I want to display default values in my input fields, so I followed [answers in this stack overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31542032/how-to-add-default-values-to-input-fields-in-thymeleaf) (basically replacing th:field with th:value). Nevertheless when I tried to use the same strategy with textarea, it did not work. Why not? How do I achieve the same effect with a textarea?

Comment: You can use `th:text="${your_variable_here}"` or even `th:placeholder="${your_variable_here}"` if you want to use placeholder text instead of an actual value in the textarea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`<textarea />` doesn't have a value attribute.  Use `th:text` instead.

Alternatively, you could switch to `th:field` which will work the same for both `<input />` and `<textarea />`. (When you use ``th:field`, you set the default value by setting correct property on your object rather than setting it in the HTML.)