# Setting th:field from another variable in Thymeleaf

Tags: thymeleaf

I have this code below where I try to set a field with a value from the viewModel. I tried to follow [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25027801/how-to-set-thymeleaf-thfield-value-from-other-variable) and  [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31542032/how-to-add-default-values-to-input-fields-in-thymeleaf/31543370) by removing th:field and adding only th:value + html name and id but I still get null in the model. Not really sure what I am doing wrong.

```html
<tr th:each="r, rowStat : ${roomViewModels}">

<td th:text="${r.type} ">
</td>
 <td th:text="${#numbers.formatCurrency(r.price)}"></td>
<td>
<input class="form-control" type="number" min="1" max="10"
th:field="*{roomType[__${rowStat.index}__].numberOfRooms}"
id="numberOfRooms" name="numberOfRooms"/>

<input th:value="${viewModel.rooms[__${rowStat.index}__].getType()}"
name="type"
id="type"
type="hidden"/>
```

Controller

```
    @PostMapping("/create-booking")
public String createBooking(@Valid BookingBindingModel bindingModel, BindingResult br,RedirectAttributes rAtt, @AuthenticationPrincipal CustomUser user,
                            @RequestParam(value = "id") Long id){
    if (br.hasErrors()) {
        System.out.println(br);
        rAtt
                .addFlashAttribute("bindingModel", bindingModel)
                .addFlashAttribute("org.springframework.validation.BindingResult.bindingModel", br);
        return "redirect:booking-form";
    }
```

Controller:

```
    @GetMapping("/booking-form")
public String bookingForm(HttpServletRequest request, Model model) {
    Cookie[] cookies = request.getCookies();
    long id = 0;
    for (Cookie cookie : cookies) {
        if (cookie.getName().equals("id")) {
            id = Long.parseLong(cookie.getValue());
            break;
        }
    }
    AccommodationViewModel viewModel = this.accommodationService.findById(id);
    List<RoomViewModel> roomViewModels = viewModel.getRooms();
    model
            .addAttribute("viewModel", viewModel)
            .addAttribute("roomViewModels", roomViewModels);

    return "booking-form" ;
}
```

ViewModel:

```
public class AccommodationViewModel {

private Long id;
private String name;
private String category;
private String city;
private String address;
private Integer postalCode;
private String imageUrl;

private List<RoomViewModel> rooms = new ArrayList<>();
private String type;

private String cancellationPolicy;
private String paymentPolicy;
private LocalTime checkInTime;
private LocalTime checkOutTime;
```

Binding Model:

```
public class BookingBindingModel {

@Future
@DateTimeFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd")
@NotNull(message = "Check out date is required!")
private LocalDate checkOut;

@NotNull(message = "Number of rooms is required!")
private List<RoomBindingModel> roomType;

@NotNull(message = "Number of people is required!")
private Integer numberOfPeople;
```

Comment: It would be very helpful to see the data structure you have created at the Model side too. My first comment would be, don't use hard-coded HTML IDs inside the Thymeleaf loop - you are just asking for duplication and confusion. When you use `th:field` you do not need name or id to be specified. https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/2.1/thymeleafspring.html#inputs

Comment: Got it, I will remove name and id. I have added controllers , binding and view models.

Comment: Are you sure that there are the same number of `roomType` objects as there are `roomViewModels`? Or, is there meant to be a loop within a loop here somewhere?

Comment: I am not sure what you mean but here are the viewModel - size 2 and the bindingModel - size 2. https://postimg.cc/gallery/L5HcnYN No other loops. Perhaps I am missing something.

Comment: This line of code creates a loop through the `roomViewModels` list. `<tr th:each="r, rowStat : ${roomViewModels}">`. It declares a new variable `rowStat` with information about the iteration (See the documentation for more information).  Whereas this line of code `<input class="form-control" type="number" min="1" max="10"
th:field="*{roomType[__${rowStat.index}__].numberOfRooms}"
id="numberOfRooms" name="numberOfRooms"/>` tries to use the rowStat variable to access the roomType List. I think this is the crux of your error.